# Can I use Global Hooks and Raw Input at the same time?

Tags: .net, winapi, hook, keyboard-hook, setwindowshookex

I tried using Global Hooks using `SetWindowsHookEx` to get all the the keystrokes.

Problem is i cant use Global Hooks and Raw Input at the same time.

I'm thinking there must be some issue here because the Global Hooks automatically gets disabled after I enable Raw Inputs.

Comment: can i change a keystroke without setwindowex() just with  use raw input??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who told you that they needed to be used together? If your application is registered to handle raw input, there's absolutely no reason to install a global hook. The whole point of the raw input model is for an application to receive notification of and process raw input from any HID connected to the computer.

Rather, you listen for the [`WM_INPUT` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645590.aspx), which is sent to the application's message queue for any HID that you've registered by calling the [`RegisterRawInputDevices` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645600.aspx). Upon receipt of this message, your application should call the [`GetRawInputData` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645596.aspx) using the `RAWINPUT` handle contained in the `lParam` parameter of the `WM_INPUT` message. Sample code is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645546.aspx#standard_read).

Alternatively, you can do a buffered read of the raw data. This is more useful for devices that generate large amounts of input at a time. With this approach, you call the [`GetRawInputBuffer` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645595.aspx), which returns an array of `RAWINPUT` structures. Again, sample code is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645546.aspx#buffered_read).

Topical reading on the Raw Input functions is [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645536.aspx).

Comment: i used gloabalhook to change some keyboards key before and now i wanna use raw input to get input device's name(to know which one send data).but when i use rawinput  global Hooks gets disabled!

Comment: @raha: I don't understand what you're saying, and I'm not sure how much clearer I could make my answer. Raw input and global hooks are not compatible, and there's no reason you should ever need to use them together. If you've registered your app to receive raw input from a device, you don't need a global hook. You'll be notified of input via a `WM_INPUT` message. They happen at completely different levels. Raw input gets processed before a global hook does.

Comment: can i hook keyboard with raw input?so when i use rawinput,i never can hook keyboard?is that right?

Comment: @raha: The point is that registering your app to receive raw input from a device is functionally equivalent to installing a global hook. You'll get a `WM_INPUT` message each time that the device sends input to the computer, exactly as you'd be notified if you installed a global hook. The only difference is that the input you receive is at a lower level (raw) than it would be from a global hook. There's no reason to *also* hook the keyboard, you're already getting that when you get raw input notifications.

Comment: sorry i think i don't undrestand it Completely,let me say you why do i use keyboardhook.i get a key like A and send B Instead of that(if e.KeyCode==keys.A System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(B);)for this perpose at first i should hook A.

Comment: and if i have two keyboard(i have a keyboard and a barcodescanner) i have to check that A coming from witch one!(you said me before i can make a prefix for barcodescanner's input to do this,but i couldn't do that and i thought maybe i can do this with rawinput)

Comment: @raha: So, you're trying to hook a *different* keyboard than you've registered for Raw Input? Also, that's definitely *not* how you use a global hook. You don't need `SendKeys`. The whole point of a global hook is that you can modify the input event at a low level, before other applications receive the input. It sounds like you're desperately in over your head here. This isn't a particularly simple task, and if you don't understand what I've been trying to explain, you're going to have an *extremely* difficult time getting this app to work.

Comment: "The whole point of a global hook is that you can modify the input event at a low level, before other applications receive the input" u said i can change keyboard keys layout without senkey?how?

Comment: and i think if i can't to do this(use raw input and globalhook at same time)i have to configure the barcodescanner's input(i have no another choice!!)but it must has a way(somebody said we can use rawinput in child proccess and globalhook in parrent)

Comment: @raha: Umm, change the `vkCode` member of the `KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` structure. It specifies the virtual-key code of the key that was pressed. Changing it to a different virtual-key code effectively changes the character that is sent on to other applications. You'll have to make sure that you marshal the managed structure back to the `lParam` for the hook proc. Much easier if you use an existing library that already has this code written.

Comment: wow.thanks.it's nice.(but i worte it and it works now.it's hard to me to chanege it and actualy take time,but if i want to write it another time,certainly i'll do that in this way).but now,do you think that i can't use rawinput in any way if i have globalhook?

Comment: i can ask it in other way:can i do this:"change the vkCode member of the KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT structure. It specifies the virtual-key code of the key that was pressed. Changing it to a different virtual-key code effectively changes the character that is sent on to other applications.–" with rawinput?

Comment: @CODYGRAY :where can i do this:" change the vkCode member of the KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT structure. It specifies the virtual-key code of the key that was pressed. Changing it to a different virtual-key code effectively changes the character that is sent on to other applications.  –" in rawinput or keyboard hook?

Comment: @raha: No, that works with the global hook. Raw input is a different beast. You get the input before the computer even processes it. That means it hasn't converted the raw input to individual letters yet. That's your job as an application that requested to handle raw input.

Comment: @CODYGRAY ok.as i undrestood i can't change keysroke when i use rawinput.so it can run in 2 separate program at the same time.but now i have another question:can i ignore a keyboard input?(like a ps2 one).and i read it from msdn:Through the dwFlags member of RAWINPUTDEVICE, an application can select the devices to listen to and also those it wants to ignore

Comment: @raha: With raw input, the input gets passed to your application before it ever registers as a keystroke. You can change anything you want. It's your job to figure out what it means at all. It doesn't represent any keystroke at all yet. And yes, you will only get input from the devices you specify in the `dwFlags` member of the `RAWINPUTDEVICE` structure. All others will be ignored. The default, of course, is to ignore everything. You don't get raw input from a device unless you ask for it. As I mentioned before, this is a difficult task. I don't want to write the whole application for you.

Comment: @CODY GRAY:thanks for your all responses.i don't want it too!!!!(actulay english is noy my lanquage,so sometimes i can't undrestand something well).for example now i read about rawinput in msdn but can't find the dwflags value,actuly there is some value here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645565(v=vs.85).aspx but...

Comment: @raha: Yes, that's exactly it. It's the third member of the structure, `dwFlags`, typed as a `DWORD` in WinAPI terms. In C# speak, that's an `int`. The declaration would look something like this: `public struct RAWINPUTDEVICE {int usUsagePage; int usUsage; int dwFlags; IntPtr hwndTarget;}`

Comment: @cody gray:i knew that.but i dont know where can i find the dwflag's hex value:like:private const int RIDEV_INPUTSINK = 0x00000100;

Comment: @raha: Well, those values are defined in the Windows header files, but that isn't going to help you since you're working in C#, rather than C or C++. The MSDN documentation for these functions is designed for programmers writing directly to the Windows API. Since you're doing it through managed code, you have to copy the values and define the constants yourself. The custom is to put all of this inside of a class called `NativeMethods`. The [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net) site can help sometimes, but it's incomplete and sometimes wrong.

Comment: @cody gray:thanks again(and i'm realy sorry for my Boring questions)but you said:"you have to copy the values and define the constants yourself"from where?i need that value!!(for exemple when i use 0x00000030,it ignore all keyboards input,but i nedd a to ignore just a special keboard input).

Comment: You can get the flags directly from the windows header files (http://www.cs.umbc.edu/~squire/download/WinUser.h). Here they are:
#define RIDEV_REMOVE            0x00000001
#define RIDEV_EXCLUDE           0x00000010
#define RIDEV_PAGEONLY          0x00000020
#define RIDEV_NOLEGACY          0x00000030
#define RIDEV_INPUTSINK         0x00000100
#define RIDEV_CAPTUREMOUSE      0x00000200
#define RIDEV_NOHOTKEYS         0x00000200
#define RIDEV_APPKEYS           0x00000400
#define RIDEV_EXMODEMASK        0x000000F0

Comment: I need to in order to block and redirect keypresses from a particular keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a hook for the raw input which already checked by the LRESULT WindowProcedure callback. You just need to get the information back if a device was used like a mouse_pos, mouse_click (and its number of clicks which you can determine by a counter), key_input, etc...